# React modal - how to stop the user using the tab key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create my own simple modal in React which shows a grey overlay covering the screen and a box on top with the OK and Cancel button.

However all the sample code I've seen on the web (both for React and plain JS/jQuery) suffers from the same problem: while the modal is on the screen the user can use the tab key to access controls which are "greyed out" by the overlay, and hence circumvent the modality.

I've seen some suggestions about installing a global keypress event handler to discard keyboard input if the modal is open but that sounds like a bit of a bodge and not really in keeping with the component-based nature of React. Is there any cleaner way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this a bit more I've started to question what's the real benefit in this requirement.

I was trying to stop the user messing up the UI (or possibly even the back end) by getting it into a state it's not supposed to be in, but in my case he could achieve the same result using 2 windows open at the same time, and can't do anything dangerous so I've decided to live with it.